# How to increase the DNS TTL time in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, dns

How can I increase the DNS TTL time in Windows 10 through registry? Right now it's way way too low.

```
superuser.com
----------------------------------------
Record Name . . . . . : superuser.com
Record Type . . . . . : 1
Time To Live  . . . . : 30 <<<< TOO LOW!
Data Length . . . . . : 4
Section . . . . . . . : Answer
A (Host) Record . . . : 151.101.1.69
```

Comment: DNS TTL is set by domain owner for some reason (one of the reason could be ability to quickly switch to different IP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS TTL is set by the operator of the DNS server, you can't change it unless you control the DNS server.  Low TTLs can be used as @Alex says to allow a change in DNS to propagate quickly through other DNS servers.

This is not related to the TTL field in IPv4 packets (which is more accurately termed "Hop Limit" as it is in IPv6).  If you are having an issue with connections dropping out or being slow, this probably wouldn't be the cause of it.

Comment: So I need essentially a DNS caching proxy?

Comment: DNS is a distributed database, meaning DNS records can either have information (authoritative) or point to another server that has the information (non-authoritative).  The TTL controls how long a DNS server assume a record from an authoritative server is valid.  It will return a cached IP until that time expires.  Unless you are running your own DNS server this doesn't apply or affect you - and if you really need this to look different you would have to run your own local DNS server and override the record with your own.

Comment: You can always use tools like `dig` I think to query the authoritative server yourself and check for inconsistencies.

Comment: Yeah something like BIND or Acrylic DNS Proxy would do.